# Why is exception handler middleware logging "unhandled exception" when it's actually handled?

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core

I have a very simple exception handler middleware in my application:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(a =>a.Run(async context =>{
  var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get < IExceptionHandlerPathFeature > ();
  var exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error;

  var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
    error = exception.GetType().ToString(),
    message = exception.Message
  });
  context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

  if (exception is NotFoundException) {
    context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
  }
  else {
    context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
  }

  await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
}));
```

When I throw `NotFoundException`, the middleware catches the exception and returns a 404 to the client with a message as expected. However, for some reason, it logs the whole exception stack trace and tells me that the exception is unhandled.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
```

If the exception is actually being handled by the middleware, why does it log the stack trace and says the exception isn't being handled? What can I do to keep my logs clean other than returning a `NotFound()` directly at the controller level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "unhandled exception" is from controller's perspective ([document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#exception-filters-1)).

> These filters handle any unhandled exception that occurs during the execution of a controller action or another filter.

To answer why the log says the exception isn't being handled, you can check source code of [ExceptionHandlerMiddleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs#L108),

```
private async Task HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
{
    _logger.UnhandledException(edi.SourceException);
    // Exclude the rest of implementation
}
```

where [UnhandledException](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/DiagnosticsLoggerExtensions.cs#L13) logs "unhandled exception".

```
// ExceptionHandlerMiddleware & DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware
private static readonly Action<ILogger, Exception> _unhandledException =
    LoggerMessage.Define(LogLevel.Error, new EventId(1, "UnhandledException"), "An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.");
```

Comment: thanks Han, so I'm assuming this also means there's no way to prevent these logs from appearing? it's just part of how the exception handler middleware works?

Comment: @jgozal - Exactly. That log message comes from ASP.NET Core framework, so there is no workaround.

Answer (score 3):

You could disable logging for the entire `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics` category by specifying something similar in your `appsettings.json`.

```
{
  "Logging": {
   "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "Critical" // this is the relevant category
   }
  },
  // [...]
}
```

Comment: Clever idea. Though I'd use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` so only that class' error logs are suppressed.